# NGINX has to be frequently restarted on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, webserver, nginx

I set up a [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/) server on my Raspberry Pi 3B running the latest [DietPi](https://dietpi.com/). I installed [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) as the reverse proxy for the [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/) website I host. Everything works perfectly, except after a couple of hours (sometimes more often) the website can't be reached. Once the [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) service is restarted, everything works fine immediately again. So for now I have to restart the service pretty frequently. As a temporary workaround, I already set up a cronjob every hour that restarts the reverse proxy, but apparently not even that is frequent enough. The `error.log` doesn't have any content.
How can I determine and solve the issue?

The proxy failed again, so I checked the error.log and it is definitely empty. The output for `service nginx status` is as follows:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-11-09 08:05:09 CET; 17min ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 14459 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, s
  Process: 6409 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 19805 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 6411 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      CPU: 121ms

Nov 09 08:05:01 hostname systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Nov 09 08:05:09 hostname nginx[19805]: nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "git.domain.tld" in /etc/nginx/sites-en
Nov 09 08:05:09 hostname nginx[19805]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Nov 09 08:05:09 hostname systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 09 08:05:09 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Nov 09 08:05:09 hostname systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 09 08:05:09 hostname systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Perhaps running out of memory? Check your config, the error log shouldn't be empty.

Comment: Does this happen even if you don't serve any sites (disable all sites) and make the nginx available only from local network?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen I edited my question.

Comment: That (status log) says that your configuration is not correct. Can you check that, please?

Comment: I assume, it wouldn't run at all, if it was incorrect. A couple of hours ago I added a `resolver` and used a variable instead of the actual address for `proxy_pass` and so far it's working well. Once I will be sure that it worked, I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was focusing on the error

`nginx[19805]: nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream`

and found a working solution, that is described [here](https://sandro-keil.de/blog/let-nginx-start-if-upstream-host-is-unavailable-or-down/).

I edited my `git.domain.tld.vhost` file within `/etc/nginx/sites-available` so it would look like this:

```
server {
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  listen 80;
  server_name git.domain.tld;

  location / {
    set $upstream "git.domain.tld:5016";
    proxy_pass http://$upstream;
  }
}
```

As you see here, I assigned the domain that is being redirected to, to a variable. I also set the `resolver` to the DNS address which the domain is on. Now everything works as it should.